# Deploy Two Different Connecttor to Kafka Connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a topic in Kafka connect, and i want to write data to two different locations. For this, I have two custom connectors.

**I'm not working on the Confluent Platform.** I'm only working on the kafka cluster, and i plan to use `connect-distributed.sh` of kafka.

But, I don't know how can i deploy these different jobs. Should I create two distributed.properties file, and deploy they on the different ports?

Also, should I put each properties and connector jar files to each node of kafka cluster?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Connect isn't unique to Confluent Platform. As answered and shown in the Kafka documentation, you'd use the REST API to create additional connectors

> different connectors can not use the same group.id as well as the same offset/status/config topics

The group id (for sink connectors) would be unique for the name of the connector, not shared, even if you consumed the same topics

The offsets are stored for source connectors, and the configs and statuses again are separated by connector name, not meant to be unique to the running Connector. Plus those topics can't be changed via the REST API, anyway

> should I put each properties and connector jar files to each node of kafka cluster

Connect should be ran separately from brokers, but you'd place them in the plugin path that you set in the Connect properties file

Comment: I have two sink different sink connectors. So, can i use the same offset/config/status topics for these different connectors? Or can i use only config and status topics for these different connectors? Or should I create new topics for all connectors?

Comment: Once you startup a Distributed Connect cluster, they must all share the same status/offset/config topics and internal group id, but that group id is completely different from any of the actual Connector groups...

Comment: So, how kafka manages offsets for different sink connectors? Because, topics are shared

Comment: Consumer group offsets are stored in the internal __consumer_offsets topic for all consumers, including sink connectors. The consumer group name is based on the connector name. And the Connector name that is posted needs to be unique. The offsets topic in Connect is only for sources

Answer (score 0):

When running Kafka Connect in the distributed mode, you configure the connectors using an REST API. The API is described in the [Kafka docs](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_rest). Basically, you take the properties file, convert it to JSON and post it to `connect-address:8083/connectors`. For example:

```
curl \
-X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{ "name": "my-connector", "config": { "connector.class": "MyConnectorClass", "tasks.max": "3", "topics": "my-topics", "some-other-option": "some-value" } }' \
http://localhost:8083/connectors
```

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I have two different connectors. One connect-distirbuted.properties means one service. And I can not deploy two connector to the same service/port/distributed.properties. Because, different connectors can not use the same group.id as well as the same offset/status/config topics. Thus, should I deploy two different service(distributed.properties) for two different connectors?

Comment: Ah, ok ... if the connectors conflict with each other, you have to run the distributed connect twice then. Just copy the properties file, change the configurations (port, consumer group, topic names) and start two separate services of Kafka Connect.